# How to sort through a report, and send one e-mail to each recipient, with all key values?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a list of managers and their clients on sheet "publico".

I need to send a report to each manager, with their clients on the e-mail body.

For example: Manager "ag1126ct18@teste.com" would receive the lines 2 and 3 from the "publico" sheet.

The list is attached here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jLkrWqZY9s2Kt2vy_cIMMRAd1H5iDCzg/view?usp=sharing

I have a somewhat functional code that runs through the table and send emails to managers, but it is sending an e-mail each time if finds the manager, repeating the e-mail each time if finds the same manager.

Another issue is I can't figure out how to add the lines in the mail body.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'envia o email com registro de log

    Dim dictMails As Object, k, rw
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim corpodoemail As String
    Dim AssuntoEmail As String
    Dim contator As Integer

    contador = 1

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'Agrupa as linhas correlatas por destinatário do e-mail
    Set dictMails = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For Each cell In Sheets("publico").Range("H2:H2000").Cells

        destinatario = cell.value
        If Len(destinatario) = 0 Then destinatario = cell.Offset(1, 0).value
        If Len(destinatario) > 0 Then
            If Not dictMails.exists(destinatario) Then
                Set dictMails(destinatario) = New Collection 'to hold the linked rows
            End If
            dictMails(destinatario).Add cell.Row 'record this row
        End If
    Next cell

    'loop over the distinct recipients and their related rows
    For Each k In dictMails.keys

        Debug.Print "Recipient: " & k

        'build up the email body
        'corpodoemail = Sheets("CAPA").Range("F11").value & "<br><br>" & _
          Sheets("CAPA").Range("F13").value & "<br><br>"

        'etc etc
        'add the information from the linked rows

        For Each rw In dictMails(k)
            Debug.Print "    Row: " & rw
            With Sheets("publico").Rows(rw)
                corpodoemail = "<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:" & _
                  "collapse;}</style></head><body>" & _
                  "<table style=""width:50%""><tr>" & _
                  "<th bgcolor=""#D8D8D8"">MCI</th><th bgcolor=""#D8D8D8"">PRODUTO</th>" & _
                  "<th bgcolor=""#D8D8D8"">DATA</th></tr><tr>" & _
                  "<th>" & .Cells(1).value & "</th>" & "<th>" & .Cells(2).value & "</th>" & "<th>" & .Cells(4).value & "/" & .Cells(5).value & "</th>" & _
                  "<th>" & .Cells(12).value & "</th>" & "<th>" & .Cells(12).value & "</th>" & "<th>" & .Cells(14).value & "/" & .Cells(55).value & "</th>"
            End With
        Next rw

        AssuntoEmail = Sheets("CAPA").Range("F8").value
        Set Email = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
        With Email
            .To = k
            .subject = AssuntoEmail
            .HTMLBody = corpodoemail
        End With

        Email.Send

    Next k 'próximo gerente

End Sub
```

How can I send one e-mail to each manager, and include the list with all the clients?

To make it more clear:

Client 1 and 2 from the list, belongs to branch 1126, manager 18, so the script must send and e-mail with line 2 and 3 of the sheet to said manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it. Some parts of your code removed so the overall approach is more obvious: it should be clear what you need to add back.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'envia o email com registro de log

    Dim dictMails As Object, k, rw
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim html As String

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'start by grouping all rows related by the recipient...
    Set dictMails = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each cell In Sheets("publico").Range("H2:H2000").Cells
        'recipient, or default recipient?
        destinatario = cell.value
        If Len(destinatario) = 0 Then destinatario = cell.Offset(1, 0).value

        If Len(destinatario) > 0 Then
            If Not dictMails.exists(destinatario) Then
                Set dictMails(destinatario) = New Collection 'to hold the linked rows
            End If
            dictMails(destinatario).Add cell.Row 'record this row
        End If
    Next cell

    'loop over the distinct recipients and their related rows
    For Each k In dictMails.keys

        Debug.Print "Recipient: " & k 

        'build up the email body
        html = "<head><style>table, th, td " & _
              "{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:" & _
              "collapse;}</style></head><body>"

        html = html & "Here is your information:<br><br>"

        'open the table
        html = html & "<table style=""width:50%""><tr>" & _
           "<th bgcolor=""#D8D8D8"">MCI</th><th bgcolor=""#D8D8D8"">" & _
           "PRODUTO</th><th bgcolor=""#D8D8D8"">DATA</th></tr>"


        'add one row for each linked row
        For Each rw In dictMails(k)
            Debug.Print "    Row: " & rw
            With Sheets("publico").Rows(rw)

               html = html & "<tr><td>" & .Cells(1).value & "</td>" & _
                 "<td>" & .Cells(2).value & "</td>" & _
                "<td>" & .Cells(4).value & "/" & .Cells(5).value & "</td>" & _
                "<td>" & .Cells(12).value & "</td>" & _
                "<td>" & .Cells(12).value & "</td>" & _
                "<td>" & .Cells(14).value & "/" & .Cells(55).value & "</td></tr>"

            End With
        Next rw

        html = html & "</table></body></html>"  '<< close the mail

        'send the mail for this recipient....

    Next k 'next recipient

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, that works flawlessly!

I think you saw from my modules that I have been trying several diferent approachs on this task, and I'm hitting walls every time. Thank you!

Do you think you can tip me off on how to insert the actual lines in the mail body?

Comment: Ops. Only now I understood these lines: corpodoemail & "<br>" & _
                              .Cells(1).value & ", " & _
                              .Cells(12).value

Thanks!

Comment: Nearly there.

Everytime I loop on "corpodoemail", the .cells(n).value resets to the next data. How do I storage this itens and list it all in the e-mail body?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to do, but I'm not following the issue - I thought there was some common info which goes at the top of the mail, and then a listing of information taken from the rows associated with each recipient.

Comment: Yep, definitely stuck on the e-mail building. I'm doing the above, but it only gathers the last itens from the rw.

corpodoemail = "<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:" & _
        "collapse;}</style></head><body>" & _
        "<table style=""width:50%""><tr>" & _
        "<th bgcolor=""#D8D8D8"">MCI</th><th bgcolor=""#D8D8D8"">PRODUTO</th>" & _
         "<th bgcolor=""#D8D8D8"">DATA</th></tr><tr>" & _
        "<th>" & .Cells(1).value & "</th>" & "<th>" & .Cells(2).value & "</th>" & "<th>" & .Cells(4).value & "/" & .Cells(5).value & "</th>"

Comment: I can take a look later if you can update your shared file with your current code and an example of the expected output for a recipient who has >1 row

Comment: Tim, what you did is perfectly. My problem that I have to build an ordenated list to send in the e-mail. I'm using the HTML layout I just posted, but my problem is: I will face some managers with several clients, and some with only a few. How to automatically build an formated list to send the information with such variable data set?

From what I could gather, .Cells(1) is storaging the first Client ID, and .Cells(12) is storaging the second. On a virtually non exaustive list, I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I've updated the code on the question to reflect the changes I made on the code you provided

Thank you so much for the support!

Comment: Each `rw` should only add one row to your table, but you're building the whole thing each time through the `rw` loop.  Build the top of the table, enter the loop and add one row per iteration, then close the table when you get out of the loop

Comment: Yep. That is is.

The problem with coding once in a million years, is that when you need to do it, every step is a cringe.

Thanks Tim!